# Cloudformation - Connect multiple stack together

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have created the stack VPC, ec2-instance and rds. I have succussfully connected the ec2-instance with VPC template but the problem that I am facing is that how to connect rds with vpc and ec2-instance **both**. I want to give SubnetB to the rds from vpc template and I want to give webserver to the security group of rds.

Vpc template

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.1.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  InternetRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
  SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: "Internet Group"
      GroupDescription: "SSH traffic in, all traffic out."
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "22"
          ToPort: "22"
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
Outputs:
  vpcID:
    Description: VPC id
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-VpcID"
  PublicSubnet:
    Description: public subnet
    Value: !Ref SubnetA
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-PublicSubnet"
   Public1Subnet:
    Description: public1 subnet
    Value: !Ref SubnetB
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-Public1Subnet"
```

Ec2 template:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  SourceStackName:
    Description: "Source stack name"
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    Default: "shifa-vpc"
Resources:
  webserver:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: sg-webserver
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
      GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-VpcID"
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: "8"
            VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      IamInstanceProfile: !Ref ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile
      KeyName: ky-webserver
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - Description: Primary network interface
          DeviceIndex: 0
          SubnetId:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-PublicSubnet"
          GroupSet:
            - Ref: sg-webserver
Outputs:
  ec2:
    Description: ec2
    Value: !Ref server
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-server"
```

Rds template

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:  
  MyDB:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      DependsOn: myDBSubnetGroup
      Properties:
        VPCSecurityGroups:
          - !Ref DBEC2SecurityGroup
        AllocatedStorage: "5"
        DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
        Engine: MySQL
        EngineVersion: "5.7.22"
        DBName: shifadb
        MasterUsername: shifadb
        MasterUserPassword: shifa123a
        MultiAZ: false
        DBSubnetGroupName: MySubnetGroup
    myDBSubnetGroup:
      Properties:
        DBSubnetGroupName: MySubnetGroup
        DBSubnetGroupDescription: subnet group
        SubnetIds:
          - !Ref SubnetA
          - !Ref SubnetB
      Type: "AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup"
    DBEC2SecurityGroup:
      Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
      Properties:
        GroupDescription: Open database for access
        VpcId: !Ref VPC
        SecurityGroupIngress:
          - IpProtocol: tcp
            FromPort: 3306
            ToPort: 3306
            SourceSecurityGroupId: !Ref webserver
```

I have  understood how to connect one template with one template. But having trouble to connect rds template with 2 templates.

Answer (score 0):

There were **multiple mistakes** in the templates. I **fixed them all** and now they deploy. I **verified** that in `us-east-1` region, thus  I had to modify them to work in this region. If you need **different region**, you need to change accordingly.

You can study the templates and you will know how to "connect multiple stack together".

Also I did not change their functionality, e.g. if you can connect to the rds from the instance. I only verified the deployment process.

**vpc**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/16
      EnableDnsSupport: true
      EnableDnsHostnames: true
      InstanceTenancy: default
  InternetGateway:
    Type: AWS::EC2::InternetGateway
  VPCGatewayAttachment:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      InternetGatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.1.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: true
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1b
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 11.0.0.0/24
      MapPublicIpOnLaunch: false
  RouteTable:
    Type: AWS::EC2::RouteTable
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
  InternetRoute:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    DependsOn: VPCGatewayAttachment
    Properties:
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      GatewayId: !Ref InternetGateway
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
  SubnetARouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetA
  SubnetBRouteTableAssociation:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SubnetRouteTableAssociation
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref RouteTable
      SubnetId: !Ref SubnetB
  SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: "Internet Group"
      GroupDescription: "SSH traffic in, all traffic out."
      VpcId: !Ref VPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: "22"
          ToPort: "22"
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
Outputs:
  vpcID:
    Description: VPC id
    Value: !Ref VPC
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-VpcID"
  PublicSubnet:
    Description: public subnet
    Value: !Ref SubnetA
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-PublicSubnet"
  Public1Subnet:
    Description: public1 subnet
    Value: !Ref SubnetB
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-Public1Subnet"
```

**ec2**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Parameters:
  SourceStackName:
    Description: "Source stack name"
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    Default: "shifa-vpc"
Resources:
  webserver:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: webserver-sg
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
          Description: For traffic from Internet
      GroupDescription: Security Group for demo server
      VpcId:
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-VpcID"
  EC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: "true"
            VolumeSize: "8"
            VolumeType: gp2
      ImageId: ami-09d95fab7fff3776c # ami-0bdcc6c05dec346bf
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      #IamInstanceProfile: !Ref ListS3BucketsInstanceProfile
      #KeyName: ky-webserver
      NetworkInterfaces:
        - Description: Primary network interface
          DeviceIndex: 0
          SubnetId:
            Fn::ImportValue:
              Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-PublicSubnet"
          GroupSet:
            - !Ref webserver
Outputs:
  ec2:
    Description: ec2
    Value: !Ref EC2Instance
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-server"

  sgGroupId:
    Description: ec2
    Value: !GetAtt webserver.GroupId
    Export:
      Name:
        Fn::Sub: "${AWS::StackName}-sgid"
```

**rds**

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Parameters:
  SourceStackName:
    Description: "Source stack name"
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    Default: "shifa-vpc"

  Ec2StackName:
    Description: "Ec2 Source stack name"
    Type: String
    AllowedPattern: "^[a-zA-Z][-a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
    Default: "ec2"    

Resources:  
  MyDB:
      Type: AWS::RDS::DBInstance
      DependsOn: myDBSubnetGroup
      Properties:
        VPCSecurityGroups:
          - !Ref DBEC2SecurityGroup
        AllocatedStorage: "5"
        DBInstanceClass: db.t2.micro
        Engine: MySQL
        EngineVersion: "5.7.22"
        DBName: shifadb
        MasterUsername: shifadb
        MasterUserPassword: shifa123a
        MultiAZ: false
        DBSubnetGroupName: !Ref myDBSubnetGroup
  myDBSubnetGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::DBSubnetGroup
    Properties:
      DBSubnetGroupName: MySubnetGroup
      DBSubnetGroupDescription: subnet group
      SubnetIds:
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-PublicSubnet"
        - Fn::ImportValue:
            Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-Public1Subnet"
  DBEC2SecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Open database for access
      VpcId: 
        Fn::ImportValue:
          Fn::Sub: "${SourceStackName}-VpcID"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 3306
          ToPort: 3306
          SourceSecurityGroupId: 
            Fn::ImportValue:
              Fn::Sub: "${Ec2StackName}-sgid"
```